# How to run appclient inside a deployed ear on wildfly?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

I have an EAR-File containing an EJB-module, a WAR-module and two appclient-modules. I deployed the EAR using maven, so the EAR-File is not placed in the standalone/deployments-directory.

Connecting with jboss-cli.sh, I can see the deployment. The application is running and available via web browser.

Now I want to run one of the appclient-modules via command line. But I can not figure out how this is done, because I don't have the EAR-File available on the harddrive (it seems that an unzipped version is somewhere in standalone/tmp/vfs/...).

If the EAR was in standalone/deployments I would run:

```
./appclient.sh --host=127.0.0.1 path/to/myear.ear#appclient-module.jar
```

How can I run the appclient-module.jar contained by the deployed EAR? I tried using the deployment-name with the appclient.sh script:

```
./appclient.sh --host=127.0.0.1 deployment-name.ear#appclient-module.jar
```

But this results in:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS013239: Could find application client /opt/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/bin/deployment-name.ear
    at org.jboss.as.appclient.subsystem.Main.main(Main.java:135)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:312)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:460)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no solution to the problem I described, so I came up with a workaround:

I am now using the maven-antrun-plugin to upload a copy of the deployed EAR-File. This second EAR-File is used in the cron-job.